# Enabling specific SSL protocols with Android WebViewClient

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, webviewclient

My application uses `WebViewClient` to make SSL connections to the server.
The server is configured to only accept TLSv1.1 and above protocols.

1. How do I check which SSL protocols are a) Supported and b) Enabled by default  when using Android `WebViewClient` on a device.
2. How do I enable specific SSL protocols for Android WebViewClient instance used in my application.

On one of the test devices running Android 4.3,
`WebViewClient` throws `onReceivedError` callback with the following description:

> "Failed to perform SSL handshake"

Chrome logs are as follows:

```
01-29 15:58:00.073 5486 5525 W chromium_net: external/chromium/net/http/http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc:865: [0129/155800:WARNING:http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc(865)] Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: 10.209.126.125:443 01-29 15:58:00.083 5486 5525 E chromium_net: external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:792: [0129/155800:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107
```

My application also uses `HttpClient` and `HttpsUrlConnection` classes to setup SSL Connections. I was able to use `SSLSocket` API to enable specific protocols when using these classes.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledProtocols(java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledProtocols(java.lang.String%5B%5D))

I need to do the same with `WebViewClient`.

Comment: AFAIK the enabled protocols WebView can not be cahnged by an App. What protocols are supported or not depends on the Android version. For TLS 1.1 and higher you need an Android 4.4 or newer (see [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=4.3)).

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I'm working on a project currently where we need to fallback from TLS v1.2 to 1.1 for three non-production test servers. We're trying to use something like this:

    adb shell 'echo "browser --show-fps-counter --ssl-version-min=tls1.1 --ssl-version-max=tls1.1" > /data/local/tmp/webview-command-line'

The FPS counter shows on an Android L tablet but not on Android TV (which is weird as they should be the same webview code). The ssl-version flags don't seem to work; a tcpdump capture from the device still shows TLS v1.2 being used.

Any help would be great.

Comment: @user802467 Did you find solution for the issue ?? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 No, I couldn't find a way to configure this in WebViewClient. I think comment above from Robert is correct.

Comment: https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/

Answer (score 8):

As per documenation it is NOT possible to support TLS 1.0 in WebView in Android < 4.3. For Android 4.4 it is disabled by default.

Check this chart for support of TLS 1.0 in different browsers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers

Comment: Do you mean "...to support TLS 1.1" (instead of 1.0) ?

Comment: It says `Disabled by default​` from 4.1 to 4.4. So how to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

If your app is using, or you are willing to use, Google Play services, you can use newer security features on older phones by installing their `Provider`. It is easy to install, only one line (plus exception handling, etc).  You will also need to add google play services to your gradle file if you do not already have it.  `ProviderInstaller` is included in the `-base` package.

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
     // Fix it
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     // Skip it
}
```

For a full example, see ["Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits"](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html) from Google.

Comment: Note: This is the synchronous call that is called on the main thread (the UI thread). You can run this call in a SyncAdapter that operates in the background or an AsyncTask to perform this attempt to update, or call using the installIfNeededAsync version of this call to avoid blocking the main thread

Comment: Also, even after installing the provider successfully, you need to enable TLS 1.2/TLS 1.1 explicitly while making https request in Android Versions between [16-20]. I verified this on a KITKAT device.

Comment: Note: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue with 4.1.2 clients.

Comment: @frank lowest version I managed to get it working was 4.4.2. Intercepting socket creation and calling `setEnabledProtocols` seems to be the only solution there.

Comment: Does this still work for anyone? I've noticed my 4.4 devices no longer load TLS 1.2 served content.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I managed to make it work, but you need okHttp library for that.
Try this when you're setting up browser activity:

```
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        private OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            Request okHttpRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
            try {
                Response response = okHttp.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute();
                return new WebResourceResponse(response.header("Content-Type", "plain/text"), response.header("Content-Encoding", "deflate"), response.body().byteStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Also, you'll need classic Trust Manager Manipulator, SSL socket factory and its implementation in your Application class:

```
public class TrustManagerManipulator implements X509TrustManager {


    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] acceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL()
    {

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new TrustManagerManipulator() };
        }
        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return acceptedIssuers;
    }
}
```

SSl Socket Factory:

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] managers = new TrustManager[] { new TrustManagerManipulator() };
        context.init(null, managers, new SecureRandom());
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

App class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static App appInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        setupSSLconnections();
    }

    private void setupSSLconnections() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I only see plain text in my webView; it probably depends on the execution of javaScript. Also found this post https://artemzin.com/blog/android-webview-io/

Comment: @ar-g Have you solved your problem?Please let me know if you done it.

Comment: @AlexanderZarovniy the problem was in 3rd-party service, we use different scheme for android below 4.4(it's not related to android)

Answer (score 0):

it's beause android 4.3 not support TSL 1.1 but only TSL1.0
read this article 
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html
find android 4.3 will see

Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 No
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   INSECURE    Yes
SSL 2   No

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer appears to suggest much the same as the first comment on the OP. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.