# Enabling TLS 1.2 on Cordova app for Android 4.1 through 5.0

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

I have an android app that fails on android 4.1 through 5.0. The issue is that the API it connects to requires TLS 1.2.

The [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) say that TLS 1.2 is supported but not enabled by default. I haven't been able to find a way to enable it with cordova; how would one enable TLS 1.2 on an android / cordova app?

It appears it would have to be enabled for the webview, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329652/enabling-specific-ssl-protocols-with-android-webviewclient) states it's impossible.. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@evandentremont,
short of a [plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=tls) (of which the 2 only work for iOS), your next best option is to set the `minSDK` in your `config.xml`

This article confirms that with API level 20, [tls 1.2 is turned on by default](http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/); the official Android [confirms this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)

Holly Schinsky has [a description](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/) on how to add this and other important features.

The link you need to add looks like this:
`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />`

Best of Luck

Comment: Yes, this is what we ended up doing.

Comment: @evandentremont Did you write a plugin. If so this would be exactly what I'm after now. It's not open source or anything is it???

Comment: No, ended up disabling android 4

Comment: excluding users with android  < 20 is not a soution