# Android < 4.3 WebView https error: Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant

Tags: android, webview, ssl-certificate

My app contains a `WebView` that load an https `url`. I've noticed that on Android version > `4.3` all works well, but on lower version i get this error:

```
external/chromium/net/http/http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc:865: [0804/151708:WARNING:http_stream_factory_impl_job.cc(865)] Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: :443
```

and `"page not found"` message appears. Https page is a `TLS v 1.2` and i've read that older version of Android does not support this kind of certificate.

So, if i use something like `SSLv3`, i'm guarantee that everything will works well on most of `Android` versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to support `TLS 1.0` in `WebView` on `Android < 4.3`. For `Android 4.4` it is disabled by default.

**According to:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763737/4409113

It is(`SSL 3.0`) enabled by default for:

> Android 1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6, 2.0–2.1, 2.2–2.2.3

And:

> Android 2.3–2.3.7, 3.0–3.2.6, 4.0–4.0.4

And:

> Android 5.0-5.0.2

But, seems like, ***it is not enabled for***:

> Android 5.1-5.1.1
>
> Android 6.0-6.0.1

So, yes, it should work.you can trust the following link:

**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:TLS/SSL_support_history_of_web_browsers**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to find a ssl protocol that works on most Android versions

Comment: Seems like `TLS 1.0` supports most of the version...but, that's because of `FREAK` or `Logjam`.you may want to take a look.