# flutter_webview_plugin: Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443

Tags: flutter, paypal

I try to go to the page www.sandbox.paypal.com with Webview in Android version 4.4.2 and I get the error: Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WebviewScaffold(
      url: url,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget webview'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '},
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Center(
          child: Align(
            child: Text(''),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android < 4.3 WebView https error: Falling back to SSLv3 because host is TLS intolerant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018510/android-4-3-webview-https-error-falling-back-to-sslv3-because-host-is-tls-int)

Comment: it's a duplicate but that one does not actually contain a solution, whereas others do - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329652/enabling-specific-ssl-protocols-with-android-webviewclient?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to support TLS 1.0 in WebView on Android < 4.3. For Android 4.4 it is disabled by default.

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763737/4409113