# Android Webview: E/chromium: [ERROR: ssl_client_socket_impl. cc (1141)]

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When I load my https url into webview in android, I got the error in logcat like below

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1141)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

Due to this CSS and JS is not loaded into webview properly.

I have gone through the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763737/998676). But when I load the same URL at second time it's working properly. I am using android 5.0.

Please some help me out from this issue.

Comment: Looks like a network problem? https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/net/base/net_error_list.h#L91

Comment: Added active connection status check as well. Still, I am facing the issue.

Comment: Hm. Strange. SSL error code 1 means SSL_ERROR_SSL, a internal error. https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-boringssl-docs/ssl.h.html#SSL_ERROR_SSL

Comment: I didn't get callback onReceivedSslError.

Answer (score 9):

use

```
 @Override
 public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
     handler.proceed();
 }
```

in your set webview client method

Comment: you cant upload to playstore with it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution for WebView.

```
private void loadWebView(String myUrl) {

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(StartModelTest.this);
    progressdialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    /* JS start*/
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    /*  JS start*/

    Log.d("TAG", "loadWebView: "+myUrl);
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (!progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Started: ");
                progressdialog.show();
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("TAG", "Finished: ");
            }
            //Log.d("TAG", "onPageFinished Bool: " + url.contains("home"));
            if (url.contains(Util.CLOSING_TAG)) {
                finish();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("TAG", "Err: ");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Same error was happened for me and I solved this way. please have a look.**

```
webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
      override fun onReceivedSslError(
        view: WebView?,
        handler: SslErrorHandler?,
        error: SslError?
      ) {
        showSSLErrorDialog(handler)
      }
    }
```

//and the error handler dialog is below

```
  private fun showSSLErrorDialog(handler: SslErrorHandler?) {

val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
builder.setTitle("APP NAME")
builder.setMessage("SOME THING WRONG")
builder.setPositiveButton("YES"){dialog, which ->
            // Do something when user press the positive button
           handler?.proceed()   

//do some other things

      
        }
builder.setNegativeButton("No"){dialog,which ->
           handler?.cancel()
//do some other things
        }
val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()

  }
```

**hope it will help**